# Book that considers stochastic interest rate models in discrete time?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, swaps

Are there any books that covers interest rate swaps, futures, forwards etc. but have a discrete time model? I would like to go deeper into this without having to worry about the stochastic calculus.

Do you have any book recommendation?

Comment: None of the products you mention requires stochastic calculus. It's really just cost of carry and discounting. Check out the book Investments from Zvi Bode, Alex Kane, Alan J. Marcus and Ravi Jain. I have the Asia global edition and find it very good for undergraduate students. Also has plenty of applications and excel work.